# How to add trailing slash to end of URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|ico|zip|rar|png|jpg|gif|pdf)$ index.php [L]
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
```

and I need to know how to add trailing slash to end of URL when I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

for add `www` in `.htaccess`
For example URL without code for this:

> www.example.com/introduction

and with this code:

> www.example.com/introduction/

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.recension4u.com/$1/ [R=301,L]`
How about just adding the slash? Does this not work?

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya, I've approved your edit, but please be careful because you added an extraneous incorrect backtick: some reviewers would have rejected the edit for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# add a trailing slash to non-files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|ico|zip|rar|png|jpe?g|gif|pdf)$ index.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

RULE FOR IIS USERS : ADDING / TO All URL. Worked for all seo

```
   <rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)([^/])$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*?)\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```